# Erro ao salvar dados

Tags: cakephp, file-upload

Estou a aprender a utilizar o Cakephp, e estou a tentar fazer uma ferramenta para fazer uploads de imagens, usando o cake 2.4.4. o Problema é que apenas os campos `modified` e `created` são inseridos na base de dados, embora `name` e `size` também devessem ser guardados. O DebugKit mostra este log de SQL

```
INSERT INTO caketest.galleries(modified,created) VALUES ('2014-05-20 14:55:07', '2014-05-20 14:55:07')
```

Ao tentar guardar a imagem, o *controller* executa a mensagem

```
$this->Session->setFlash('O Ficheiro foi guardado com sucesso.', 'default', array('class'=>'alert flashMessageSuccess'));`
```

sempre, no entanto o ficheiro não é movido para a pasta do servidor. Qual é o problema com o meu código?

**Controller**

```
public function uploadImages(){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Inserir imagens');
        $this->layout = 'admin';
        if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')){

            $this->loadModel('Gallery');
            $file = array(
                'Gallery' => array(
                    $this->request->data['Gallery']
                    )
                );
            $this->Gallery->create();
            debug($this->request->data);
            debug($this->request->data['Gallery']);
            debug($file);
            if($this->Gallery->save($this->request->data)){
                move_uploaded_file($this->data['Gallery']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT. 'img/Gallery/' . $this->data['Gallery']['name']);
                $this->Session->setFlash('O Ficheiro foi guardado com sucesso.', 'default', array('class'=>'alert flashMessageSuccess'));
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash('Erro ao guardar o ficheiro.', 'default', array('class'=>'alert flashMessageDanger'));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Gallery extends AppModel{
    public $useTable = 'galleries';
    var $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'is_valid' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Seleccione um ficheiro por favor.'
                ),
            'is_unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'Já existe um ficheiro com este nome.'
                ),
            'extension' => array(
                'rule' => array('extension', array('gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'jpg')),
                'message' => 'O ficheiro deve estar num formato gif, jpeg, jpg ou png.'
            ),
        'size' => array(
            'sizeCheck' => array(
                'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '2MB'),
                'message' => 'O ficheiro deve ter um tamanho inferior a 2MB.'
                )
            )

        )
    );
}
```

**View**

```
echo $this->Session->flash();

echo "<br>";
echo $this->Form->create('Gallery',array('type'=>'file'));

echo "<h3><small>Seleccione uma imagem por favor.</small></h3>";
echo $this->Form->input('file', array('type' => 'file'));//file('file');
echo $this->Form->error('file', array(), array('class' => 'alert flashMessageWarning'));
echo "<br>";
echo $this->Form->submit(__('Guardar'), array('class' => 'btn btn-success','formnovalidate' => true)) ;
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Minha tabela possui as colunas:

```
 id | name | size | created | modified
```

**Debug($this->request->data)**

```
array(
    'Gallery' => array(
        'file' => array(
            'name' => '1604710_722861904399871_963210258_n.jpg',
            'type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'tmp_name' => 'C:\wamp\tmp\php2B49.tmp',
            'error' => (int) 0,
            'size' => (int) 31483
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Não entendi essa parte da sua pergunta "Ao tentar guardar a imagem, o *controller* executa a mensagem `INSERT INTO caketest.galleries(modified,created) VALUES ('2014-05-20 14:55:07', '2014-05-20 14:55:07')`"

Comment: @ErlonCharles Editei a pergunta. Enganei-me ao copiar a linha, peço desculpa.

Comment: Quais são as colunas da sua tabela?

Comment: @ErlonCharles id, name, size, created e modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo o [***CookBook***](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-your-data) seus dados precisam estar da seguinte forma para serem salvos

```
Array 
(
    [ModelName] => Array
    (
        [fieldname1] => 'value'
        [fieldname2] => 'value'
    )
)
```

O problema é com o *array* onde estão os dados a serem salvos, ele salva a imagem, mas salva apenas os dados que são salvos sem que seja necessário passar os valores que são as colunas *created* e *modified*

### Solução

Recomentdo fazer uma formatação no seu *array*, subindo os dados da chave "*file*" para o mesmo nível da própria chave ou retornar um *array* assim:

```
Array(
    'Gallery' => Array(
        'name' => '1604710_722861904399871_963210258_n.jpg',
        'size' => (int) 31483
    )
)
```

Para fazer isso o seu *controller* deve ficar assim:

```
public function uploadImages(){
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Inserir imagens');
    $this->layout = 'admin';
    if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')){

        $this->loadModel('Gallery');
        $file = array(
            "Gallery" => array(
                "name" => $this->request->data["Gallery"]["file"]["name"],
                "size" => $this->request->data["Gallery"]["file"]["size"]
                )
            );
        $this->Gallery->create();
        if($this->Gallery->save($file)){
            move_uploaded_file($this->data['Gallery']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT. 'img/Gallery/' . $this->data['Gallery']['name']);
            $this->Session->setFlash('O Ficheiro foi guardado com sucesso.', 'default', array('class'=>'alert flashMessageSuccess'));
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('Erro ao guardar o ficheiro.', 'default', array('class'=>'alert flashMessageDanger'));
        }
    }
}
```

### Mover o arquivo

Com relação à mover o arquivo a documentação do [**move-uploaded-file()**](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php) diz que:

> Se filename não for um arquivo enviado válido, então nenhuma ação ocorrerá e `move_uploaded_file()` retornará `FALSE`.
>
> Se filename for um arquivo enviado válido, mas não puder ser movido por alguma razão, nenhuma ação ocorrerá e `move_uploaded_file()` retornará `FALSE`. Adicionalmente, um alerta será emitido.

Portanto devem ser verificadas as permissões de escrita na pasta de destino, de acesso à pasta de origem a existência da pasta de destino e qualquer outra coisa que impossibilite o `move_uploaded_file()` de mover o arquivo.

Comment: Fiz a modificação, e obtenho esta mensagem `$this->Session->setFlash('Erro ao guardar o ficheiro.', 'default', array('class'=>'alert flashMessageDanger'));`. O array não foi guardado, o DebugKit mostra este SQL `SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `caketest`.`galleries` AS `Gallery` WHERE `Gallery`.`name` = '1604710_722861904399871_963210258_n.jpg'`

Comment: é exibida alguma mensagem de erro nos inputs?

Comment: Erros da validação?

Comment: é exatamente o q eu quero saber

Comment: Não. E o DebugKit mostra :
$this->validationErrors(array)
GalleryImage(array)
name(array)
0 size.
O cake está a fazer um `SELECT`, não deveria estar a fazer um `INSERT` ?

Comment: Confira a edição e teste com este *controller*

Comment: o array está como me indicou, no entanto continua a mostrar `$this->Session->setFlash('Erro ao guardar o ficheiro.', 'default', array('class'=>'alert flashMessageDanger'));` e o Cake continua a fazer o `SELECT`, de acordo com o DebugKit.

Comment: Experimentei comentar as regras de validação no model, e os dados foram inseridos na BD, no entanto o ficheiro não foi movido para a pasta.

Comment: Limpa seu banco de dados e tenta de novo, pode ser a validação pelo nome do arquivo.

Comment: Limpei a base de dados e tentei outra vez, com a validação, e não deu de novo, penso que a validação do `size` poderá estar a causar isto. No DebugKit obtenho, `$this->validationErrors(array),
Gallery(array),
name(array),
0size`.

Comment: Ao que parece estava a faltar um `)` na validação, que colocava a validação do `size` dentro da validação do `name`. Mas a Imagem não está ser guardada na pasta, não tenho que colocar também, no `$file`, o valor para `tmp_name`?

Comment: Muitissimo obrigado pela sua ajuda!